# Pandas Sum() issues

Tags: python, pandas

My current data is organised into two data frames of the same shape. Id then like to sum all columns into a single column after calculation.

I am doing this using:

```
    df = df1_kwh.multiply(df2np).sum(axis=1)
```

However when I use df.shape i get a shape of "(347,)" meaning no columns and I am then unable to add additional columns to the "sum" value column using df.insert.

What can I do to make the output of df.sum able to be manipulated by other functions?

Comment: the sum function creates a series, so you probably want to assign this to a column instead of as a df, but it's hard to tell with out any example of input and desired output data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a DataFrame you can convert from Series using [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df1_kwh.multiply(df2np).sum(axis=1).to_frame()
```

By default the column name is `0`, to change it (for example to "sum"), use:

```
df = df1_kwh.multiply(df2np).sum(axis=1).to_frame('sum')
```

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df1_kwh = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(5,5)))
df2np = 2

df = df1_kwh.multiply(df2np).sum(axis=1).to_frame('sum')
df.insert(0, 'new', 'x')
```

output:

```
  new       sum
0   x  5.670608
1   x  6.644717
2   x  5.770594
3   x  5.176273
4   x  6.276120
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

If I understand your question, it is saying that `df1_kwh` and `df2np` are "two data frames of the same shape".

Assuming they have identical column labels, your code for `multiply()` should work. If the column labels differ and the index labels are identical, then `df1_kwh.multiply(df2np, axis=0).sum(axis=1)` should work.

Since the example in your question does not use `axis=0` within `multiply()`, I'll assume your dataframes have identical column labels.

Here's a way to create a DataFrame using the result of your `sum()` and then use `insert()` to add a column:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1_kwh = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(5), 'b':range(5, 10)})
df2np = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10, 15), 'b':range(15, 20)})
df = df1_kwh.multiply(df2np).sum(axis=1).to_frame()
print(df)
df.insert(loc=1, column='additional_column', value='test')
print(df)
```

Input:

```
df1_kwh
   a  b
0  0  5
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
df2np
    a   b
0  10  15
1  11  16
2  12  17
3  13  18
4  14  19
```

Output:

```
     0 additional_column
0   75              test
1  107              test
2  143              test
3  183              test
4  227              test
```